# Cannot read property 'online' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my code I'm trying to count how many online users we have with the countOnline function.

I'm getting the error **"Cannot read property 'online' of undefined"**;

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  let amount=0;

  for(let user in usersObj){
    if(usersObj.user.online){
      amount++;
    }
  }

  return amount;
}

let a = countOnline({
  Alan: { online: false },
  Jeff: { online: true },
  Sarah: { online: false }
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Try : ‘ usersObj[user].online’ Or ‘user.online’

Comment: There is no [JSON](https://json.org) in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the property `user` where it should be a user name instead. Use `[user]` instead of `.user.` while iterating object keys.

See the fixed snippet below:

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
   let amount=0;
   for(let user in usersObj){
     if(usersObj[user].online){ // <-- see, I placed user in [ ]
       amount++;
     }
   }
   return amount; 
}
    
let a = countOnline({
   Alan: { online: false },
   Jeff: { online: true },
   Sarah: { online: false } 
});
    
console.log(a);
```

**Alternative solution**

You may iterate object values in even more clean and readable way, for example with usage of `Object.values()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), which will return you an array of all users in your case, so you need just to reduce it.

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
   return Object.values(usersObj).reduce((total, user) => user.online ? total + 1 : total, 0)
}
    
let a = countOnline({
   Alan: { online: false },
   Jeff: { online: true },
   Sarah: { online: false } 
});
    
console.log(a);
```

**And even shorter, but less performant:**

```js
let usersObj = {
   Alan: { online: false },
   Jeff: { online: true },
   Sarah: { online: false } 
};

let onlineCount = Object.values(usersObj).filter(u => u.online).length;

console.log(onlineCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access `userObj.user.online`, while it should be `userObj[user].online`:

```js
function countOnline(users) {

  let amount = 0;
  
  for (const user in users) {
    if (users[user].online) {
      amount++;
    }
  }

  return amount;
}

const a = countOnline({
  Alan: {
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    online: false
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  
  let amount=0;
  for(let user in usersObj){
    if(usersObj.online){
      amount++;
    }
      
  }
  return amount;
  
}
let a = countOnline({ Alan: { online: false }, Jeff: { online: true }, Sarah: { online: false } });

console.log(a);
```

Comment: It is incorrect too. You iterate the `usersObj` but inside of iteration you also refer to `usersObj`

Answer (score 0):

You used for in. dictionary is not iterable like arrays. you need key, value.
Just try this.

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  let amount=0;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(usersObj)) {
    if(value.online){
        amount++;
    }
}

  return amount;
}

let a = countOnline({
  Alan: { online: false },
  Jeff: { online: true },
  Sarah: { online: false }
});

console.log(a);
```

If you want to use `for in` loop in your code do like this

```
let a = countOnline([
      {Alan: { online: false }},
      {Jeff: { online: true }},
      {Sarah: { online: false }}
    ]);
```